# Problem with double quotes and Input

Tags: php, html

i have the following code :

```
 <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['msg']; ?>">
```

This input is automatically filled with the name that is writen in the previous page.
So, if the user wrote : i like "apples" and banana
The input will be broken because it will close the tag after the double quotes.
I know i can avoid that by html entiting the value, but i don't want this, is there another solution or is there an <<< EOD in html ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/htmlentities) / [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars)  is the standard way for this. You should use it.

You can always decode the entities before you send them by E-Mail, or do something else with them using [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/html_entity_decode).

Answer (score 2):

You should use the **[`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars)** function, to escape the output for HTML :

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['msg']); ?>">
```

Note : you might have to add some additionnal parameters, if you are not using `ISO-8859-1` as charset ; for example, with UTF-8 :

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['msg'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

One function or another will cause some kind of trouble.

I came up with the following to keep the ampersand:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo parseString($_GET['msg']); ?>">
<?php
function parseString($str) {
    $result=str_replace('"','&quot;',$str);
    $result=str_replace("'","&#39;",$result);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious why you created this function instead of using the built-in `htmlspecialchars`, as pointed out in the previous (correct) answers.